# Left Recursion in Grammar Results in Conflicts

Tags: c, grammar, yacc, bison, lalr

Throughout a Bison grammar I am using right recursion, and I have read that left recursion is better because it doesn't have to build the whole stack first.

However, when I try to switch to left recursion on any of them, I always end up with a lot of conflicts, and I am not seeing why.

Can anyone show me a generic example of where using left recursion instead of right causes a conflict (when the right recursion doesn't cause a conflict). Then what needs to be done when switching to left to correct such a conflict.  I think a fundamental example will help me more than just a correction of my own grammar.

**Edit:**
But I guess I should include a particular example anyways, since my understand is a little less than complete :-) Changing 'list separator command' to 'command separator list' resolves the conflict.

```
State 9 conflicts: 3 shift/reduce


Grammar

    0 $accept: input $end

    1 input: error NEWLINE
    2      | input NEWLINE
    3      | input list NEWLINE
    4      | /* empty */

    5 list: command
    6     | command separator
    7     | list separator command

    8 separator: SEMI
    9          | L_OR
   10          | L_AND

   11 command: variable_assignment
   12        | external_w_redir
   13        | external_w_redir AMP
   14        | pipeline
   15        | pipeline AMP

...

state 9

    5 list: command .
    6     | command . separator

    SEMI   shift, and go to state 18
    L_AND  shift, and go to state 19
    L_OR   shift, and go to state 20

    SEMI      [reduce using rule 5 (list)]
    L_AND     [reduce using rule 5 (list)]
    L_OR      [reduce using rule 5 (list)]
    $default  reduce using rule 5 (list)

    separator  go to state 22
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal example where you observe this effect? I don't think it works that way, and my guess is that you have some other problem with your grammar. Bison shouldn't have a problem with left or right recursion, even if left recursion is more efficient.

Comment: @Thomas Padron-McCarthy : Updated to include Bison's y.output in debug mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

I have to retract my original answer. Your left-recursive grammar does *not* seem to be ambiguous, as I first thought. I think I got confused by the extra rule which is used to make a final separator optional.

Here is a simplified version of your original, right-recursive, grammar:

```
list: COMMAND
      | COMMAND SEPARATOR
      | COMMAND SEPARATOR list
      ;
```

This grammar matches (if I'm not even more confused than I think, which is of course a possibility) the inputs C, CS, CSC, CSCS, CSCSC, CSCSCS, etc. That is, a sequence of SEPARATOR-separated COMMANDs, with an optional SEPARATOR at the end.

And this is the simplified version of your left-recursive grammar, which gives a shift/reduce conflict in Bison:

```
list: COMMAND
      | COMMAND SEPARATOR
      | list SEPARATOR COMMAND
      ;
```

If I expanded things correctly, this grammar matches the inputs C, CS, CSC, CSSC, CSCSC, CSSCSC, etc. It is not ambiguous, but it is not equivalent to your left-recursive grammar. The list of COMMANDs can not have a SEPARATOR at the end, and the SEPARATORs between the COMMANDS can be doubled.

I think the reason for the shift/reduce conflict is that Bison only looks one token ahead when it decides if to shift or reduce, and with the double separators that are introduced in the second grammar, it can sometimes get confused.

If it is important that the final separator is optional, and that the grammar must be left-recursive, I would suggest re-writing it:

```
list: separatedlist
      | separatedlist SEPARATOR
      ;

separatedlist: COMMAND
               | separatedlist SEPARATOR COMMAND
               ;
```

But I wouldn't worry about left or right, unless your lists are *really* long, or you intend to run your parser on very limited hardware. I don't think it matters much, on modern desktop computers.

Comment: If that is they case, I don't understand how it becomes ambiguous with that change.  Here is the entire y.output: http://www.pastebin.org/51936

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, it's not ambiguous. I've changed my answer. But now it's not much of an answer.

Comment: I just noticed the fact that it was matching to separators too, which is not what I want.  So I guess I need the right recursive example, or figure out how to get what your first example matches using left recursion.

Comment: But I do want that optional last SEP because it might be semi colon which is fine.  I will just check the last separator is not && or || in the action function.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion/errors seem to come from the productions for list.  Your left recursive version is:

```
list: command
    | command separator
    | list separator command
```

Your right recursive version is:

```
list: command
    | command separator
    | command separator list
```

These two rule sets are actually quite different, matching different things.  The first one matches one or more **command**s with **separator**s between them, and an optional extra **separator** after each **command**.  The second is similar, except it only allows the extra optional **separator** after the *LAST* command.

Assuming what you really want is a left-recursive version of the latter, what you want is

```
list_no_trailer: command
               | list_no_trailer separator command

list: list_no_trailer
    | list_no_trailer separator
```

The conflict in your version come from the fact that after parsing a 'command' and seeing a separator on the lookahed, it doesn;t know whether to pull that in as the optional separator after the command, or to reduce the command under the assumption that its a list separator and there will be another command right after it.  It would need 2 characters of lookahead for that, so your grammar is LR(2), but not LR(1)